# how can I check whether the session is exist or with empty value or null in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

Does anyone know how can I check whether a session is empty or null in .net c# web-applications?

Example:

I have the following code:

```
 ixCardType.SelectedValue = Session["ixCardType"].ToString();
```

It's always display me error for Session["ixCardType"] (error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object). Anyway I can check the session before go to the .ToString() ??

Comment: Have you possibly tried comparing the Session[item] against null first?

Comment: @Anthony: It's scary that this question even exists. -1 and voted to close.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something as simple as an 'if' should work.

```
 if(Session["ixCardType"] != null)    
     ixCardType.SelectedValue = Session["ixCardType"].ToString();
```

Or something like this if you want the empty string when the session value is null:

```
ixCardType.SelectedValue = Session["ixCardType"] == null? "" : Session["ixCardType"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 16):

Cast the `object` using the `as` operator, which returns `null` if the value fails to cast to the desired `class` type, or if it's `null` itself.

```
string value = Session["ixCardType"] as string;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    // null or empty
}
```

Comment: +1 for as, that is one of the coolest little-known features of C#

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the result to a variable, and test it for null/empty prior to calling ToString():

```
var cardType = Session["ixCardType"];
if (cardType != null)
{
    ixCardType.SelectedValue = cardType.ToString();
}
```